# Android SQLite getting long from database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get two floats (latitude and longitude) from a database. I know that they're being written correctly because I opened the db in an app and it says that the two values are 42.9512 and -83.4225 (just a random place that I chose to add).

I originally returned both values in a method in my db class as a bundle, but also created a method that only returns the latitude (just to test if it would work):

```
    public long getLat(long l) throws SQLException {
        String[] cols = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_ADDRESS,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE};
        Cursor c = ourDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, cols, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            long lat = c.getLong(2); //latitude column
        return lat;         
        }
        return 0l;
    }
```

The class that this value is returned to is my class that displays all of the database contents (except for the lat/long). This is part of the code:

```
    Bundle favLoc = temp.getLatLng(rowID);
    long lat = temp.getLat(rowID);      
    long lng = favLoc.getLong("lng");
    Toast.makeText(SQLView.this, "Row id: " + rowID + "\nlat: " + lat + "\nlng: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent("com.blah.blah.MAINACTIVITY");
    i.putExtras(favLoc);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();   
    break;
```

temp is an instance of my DBHelper class. I tried getting the long values from the Bundle, but I changed the code slightly to try to get the lat value with the new method I created specifically for the lat value.
I use the toast as a debugging tool just to display the value.

For some reason, the printed out value is always printed out as an int instead of a float - so the lat is get printed as 42 instead of 42.9512 and the lng is printed as -83 instead of -83.4225.

I can't seem to understand why this occurs. If anyone could help me with this issue, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking why floats are rounded when converted to longs?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

`long` is a 64bit integer type, that's why you get rounded values.

If you want to get floating point values use `float` or `double`. (Prefer `double`).

Comment: Prefer double everything I've seen geo latlng is double

Comment: I did not miss that point but he wrote "float" in his question :)